# knockout.js is too slow in filling observableArray

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, angularjs

I create test for the comparing angular and knockout:

```
    items = self.items();
    // ...
    self.items.valueHasMutated();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/imbolc/z7bkz/9/embedded/result/

Is this test correct? Do you know way for increase KO filling speed?

Comment: From what I can see, your test isn't really valid. Your jQuery test is just appending dom elements within a for loop. Your KO test is creating an array of Json objects, each Json object contains a ko.observable function. Then your Angular test is working with an array of integers.

Comment: Do you know another way to implement this test for knockout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not thoroughly compare the logic betweens your different tests, but I do know that there are some issues with how Chrome processes text nodes as described here: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues/793

If you strip the text nodes from your inline KO template, then you see a big boost in performance in Chrome.

Like:

```
<ul id="ko-list" data-bind="foreach: items"><li>ko: <span data-bind="text: val"></span></li></ul>
```

Updated sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/tsTmZ/

Sample results in the latest Chrome:

jquery:    45 ms  74 ms

angular:  171 ms 199 ms

knockout: 109 ms  25 ms

Comment: Very helpful! Need to apply this to some of the KO projects I have.

Comment: By the way, hopefully this is somewhat temporary, as it seems to already be improved in Canary.

Comment: Just handy to know for now as I have a project which is binding a long list. Speed improvements are always nice!

Comment: yep. give it a shot, at least in Chrome you should hopefully see a good improvement.

Comment: @RPNiemeyer You don't happen to know if this has the same effect when using templates within a `foreach`? e.g. `<!-- ko template: { name: 'my-template', foreach: items } --><!-- /ko -->`

Comment: @RPNiemeyer Don't worry. Updated the code above to use a template, and the speed performance is noticeable. Thanks again.