# Profiling KnockoutJS observableArray

Tags: javascript, dom, knockout.js, profiling

I want to profile an `observableArray` in KnockoutJS to see how long it's taking to fill and render the `observableArray` in HTML.

I planned to use an old school method like below. Is the results I'll get from this be accurate? Or is there a better way to do this profiling

JavaScript

```
    var arr = [],
        itemCount = 200;

    for (var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
        arr.push('item ' + i);
    }

    var t1 = new Date();
    var viewModel = {
        items: ko.observableArray(arr),
        vmName: ko.observable('View Model')
    };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    var t2 = new Date();


    console.log(t2 - t1); //Shows the time in milliseconds
```

HTML

```
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
    <div data-bind="html: $data"></div>
</div>
```

Graph I generated from the results

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520823/knockout-js-is-too-slow-in-filling-observablearray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your graph suggests, this is basically the right way to do this. This is because `ko.applyBindings` is a synchronous call. See here: [is ko.applyBindings synchronous or asynchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361615/is-ko-applybindings-synchronous-or-asynchronous)

I would make a small revision, like so, because you're not interested in profiling the time it takes to create observables. However, this time is quite negligible and would only add a tiny, if any, constant to your profiling.

```
var viewModel = {
    items: ko.observableArray(arr),
    vmName: ko.observable('View Model')
};

var t1 = new Date();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
var t2 = new Date();


console.log(t2 - t1); //Shows the time in milliseconds
```

Comment: thats a different question. :) if my question was helpful to you, please be sure to upvote and mark it as accepted

Comment: @Nips on some browsers, `console` has a lot more to offer than just `.log`. Take a look at [`.time`, `timeLine`, `timeStamp` or even `.profile`](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api#consoletimelabel).